# Android: The line of ListView behidden

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've create the listview with some information in it. It's run so good in the 320x480 version. But when I run it in the 240x320, sometime the line between 2 column be hidden (when I slide the screen, sometime it show but sometime it hidden). I don't know what's the trouble I met.

All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is mobile specific resolution fault.

To avoid that just give list divider height to 2 dip then at least one pixel wont disappear.